# How to make a sprite move within a circular boundary using accelerometer in cocos2d

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to move a sprite(ball) within a circular boundary using an accelerometer. I am able to move the sprite(ball) on an empty screen with no difficulties. But now I need to set a circular boundary so that the movement is restricted within the circle. I have a background image which is a circle kind of an image. And if at all the sprite(ball) is moving then it should be only within this circular image and I don't want the ball to move out of the circle image. I want to know how to set the boundary on the circular background image. Please help me. Thanks.

Code:

```
if((self=[super init])) 
{
  bg=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"challenge-game.png"];
      bg.position=ccp(240,160);
      bg.opacity=180;
      [self addChild:bg];

   ball1=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
   ball1.position=ccp(390,180);
   [self addChild:ball1];

    ball2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball1.png"];
    ball2.position=ccp(240,20);
    [self addChild:ball2];

    ball3=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball2.png"];
    ball3.position=ccp(100,180);
    [self addChild:ball3];

    size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    self.isAccelerometerEnabled=YES;
    [self scheduleUpdate];
  }

 -(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration 
    {
    ballSpeedY = acceleration.x*20;
     ballSpeedX = -acceleration.y*10;       
   }

-(void)updateBall1 { 
float maxY1 = size.height - ball1.contentSize.height/2;
float minY1 = ball1.contentSize.height/2;
float newY1 = ball1.position.y + ballSpeedY;
newY1 = MIN(MAX(newY1, minY1), maxY1);

float maxX1 = size.width - ball1.contentSize.width/2;
float minX1 = ball1.contentSize.width/2;
float newX1 = ball1.position.x + ballSpeedX;
newX1 = MIN(MAX(newX1, minX1), maxX1);
NSLog(@"MAXY: %f MINY: %f NEWY: %f",maxY1,minY1,newY1);
ball1.position = ccp(newX1, newY1);    
 }

-(void)setPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
 float dx=position.x-240;
 float dy=position.y-160;
 float r=bg.contentSize.width/2-ball1.contentSize.width/2;
 if((dx*dx+dy*dy)>(r*r))
 {
    position.x=100;
    position.y=100;
 }
 [super setPosition:position];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the remaining requirements are, but have you considered using Box2D and playing around with the gravity based on the accelerometer to move the sprite around? In this case, you can simply make a circular object representing your allowed world.

If this is not suitable, I guess you could force the position of you sprite to be always within your circle (override setPosition and make sure that x and y are always with a circle given by the mathematical formula).

Something like this (note that you need to decide where to place your ball when it is about to move outside the circle):

```
-(void) setPosition:(CGPoint)pos
{
    float dx = pos.x - centerX;
    float dy = pos.y - centerY;

    if ((dx * dx + dy * dy) > (r * r))
    {
        // Change pos.x and pos.y to stay within the circle.
    }

    [super setPosition:pos];
}
```

Also, the radius of the circle (`r` in the above code) should actually be the radius of your target circle minus the radius of your ball.

**Another example using the `update`**

```
// In your scene/layer initialization register update callback, like this
[self scheduleUpdate];


// Then modify your update method
- (void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    // Your update logic

    // Here you take care of your sprite.
    float dx = ballSprite.position.x - centerX;
    float dy = ballSprite.position.y - centerY;

    if ((dx * dx + dy * dy) > (r * r))
    {
        // Change the position of ballSprite to stay within the circle.
        ballSprite.position = ccp(newX, newY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nope its just COCOS2D. How do I override the setPosition method? What class does it belong to? Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CCNode` has a property `position` which is handled by an internal `setPosition:(CGPoint)` method. If you are extending CCSprite for the object you'd like to limit to this circle simply add a method `-(void) setPosition:(CGPoint)position` implementation file (.m). The `position` parameter is the target position that the sprite would like to move. Now, make sure that `position.x` and `position.y` are within a circle. If not, correct x and y and call `[super setPosition:position]`.

Comment: I am adding the image using CCSprite.

Comment: CCSprite bg=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];

Comment: In this case you will need to implement this logic in your `-(void) update:(ccTime)dt` method. Just store the reference to your sprite in your class and inside `update` make sure that sprite's position meats the constraint described in edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for staying with me. Now, its become even more worse then before. The ball sprite wont move. They are stuck at the position.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Its become even more worse now. My sprites do not move. They are stuck at their initial positions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting your current code. You can put the code from your `setPosition` in the `updateBall1` method just before you call `ball1.position = ...`. Instead of `position.x` and `position.y` use `newX1` and `newY1`. You have set 100, 100 in you code - is this the behabiour the ball should take when it hits the circle?

Comment: Yes, i have added the if condition in my updateBall1 method. When the ball hits boundary,it stops right there. Never seem to move. And that is because of the if statement.

Comment: Small correction to your example code. Condition in your if statn should be distance<r not distance>r.

Comment: Its not moving away from the boundary. Its stuck there. Any clue?? What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Help me to sort this out. I still don't seem to get this to work,